# Java XMLBeans throws NoSuchMethod error

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I have following code

```
   static {
       wsAuthenticate = WsAuthenticate.Factory.newInstance(); 
    ...
    }
```

which calls

```
public static final SchemaType type = (SchemaType) 
       XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(WsAuthenticate.class.getClassLoader(), 
           "schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sDE164C7F4147229ECE15396F7FA5432D")
       .resolveHandle("wsauthenticate751ftype");
```

in jar file containing .xsb files. 
I have used following jar files

- xBean1.0.3.jar
- xmlBeans2.3.0.jar
- xmlSchema1.4.7.jar

But I am facing following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/SchemaTypeSystem;
    at com.travis.webservices.WsAuthenticate.<clinit>(WsAuthenticate.java:19)
    at com.travis.webservices.WsAuthenticate$Factory.newInstance(WsAuthenticate.java:119)
    at com.mmi.api.ticketvala.TicketWalaMain.<clinit>(TicketWalaMain.java:64)
Exception in thread "main" 

at : 

   XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(WsAuthenticate.class.getClassLoader(),       "schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sDE164C7F4147229ECE15396F7FA5432D").resolveHandle("wsauthenticate751ftype");
```

What could be the reason and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This `typeSystemForClassLoader` method is introduced in version (2.1.0) . See [javadoc](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/reference/) checking with previous versions you can see this method is missing.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same exception when reading .xlsx file

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused By :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoadern
```

Then I"ve removed my old xmlbeans-2.0.jar and put the latest [xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlbeans230jar.htm) containing this method and it is solved now

Answer (score 0):

adding this dependency solved my problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```